# How to run php project in codeigniter using netbeans

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I have included my php project developed in Codeigniter inside Netbeans project explorer.
But when I goes to run it with URL **localhost:8004/index.php**.It shows me following error.

```
> Unable to connect  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server

> at localhost:8004.
```

I dont understand what is the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, you're better off running this in something like WAMP. As someone who uses CI on a daily basis, just go with me on this. The way they index the files and the file paths is using a routing file rather than actual file paths.

[WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: Yes. Its working using WAMP. I have tried it but I want to run it on Netbeans.

Comment: You can use the PHP.exe file to build the PHP page to check for errors, but beyond that it won't work unless you're rendering raw template